# MockitoJUnitRunner with SpringBoot 3.1.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4

having this class:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class PdfService {
    
    private final AsAPIService asAPIService;

    public PdfService(AsAPIService asAPIService) {
        this.asAPIService = asAPIService;
    }


    public void generatePdf() throws UnirestException {

        asAPIService.chart(AsRequestBody.builder()
                .authKey("6248i23")
                .authPwd("8f1adbf3deaefa8d6a4c05")
                .build());
    }
    

}
```

I have this test defined:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class PdfServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    PdfService pdfService;


    @Test
    void generatePdf() throws UnirestException {
        pdfService.generatePdf();
    }

}
```

but when I run it I have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.xiocolmenares.service.PdfService.generatePdf()" because "this.pdfService" is null
```

I also tried:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PdfServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    PdfService pdfService;


    @Test
    void generatePdf() throws UnirestException {
        pdfService.generatePdf();
    }

}
```

with the same result

Comment: Judging from your code you are mixing junit4 and junit5. Use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension)` which is for JUnit5.

Comment: What does `PdfService` look like? Typically you'd use `@Mock` with `@InjectMocks` to create an instance of `PdfService` with mocked dependencies.

Comment: I doubt you tried `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension)` or at least that it leads to the same exception. I would expect a `NullPointerException` however now on the field `asAPIService` inside the `PdfService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PdfService` must have `AsAPIService` as a field, but your test code doesn't have a mocking object of `AsAPIService` to inject into the field.

In `@InjectMocks` document, if arguments can not be found, then null is passed.

If you run success, follow below.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PdfServiceTest {
    @Mock
    AsApiService AsApiService;

    @InjectMocks
    PdfService pdfService;


    @Test
    void generatePdf() throws UnirestException {
        pdfService.generatePdf();
    }

}
```